# Relocating community cats within the same neighborhood

Tags: cats, feral

We are moving house within the same neighborhood in a couple of weeks and we have four cats (2 males, 2 females) and kittens. They were born in our yard and we feed them every day.

To describe their behavior I should say that they are very friendly and not only let us pet them but they follow us around and play with us whenever we're in the yard.

My concern is that relocating cats is advised only as a last resort as they might try to get back to their territory and get lost in the process. But we are living in a kind of a gate community so they would still be in the same "neighborhood". Please let me know what you think. Thank you very much in advance,

Sara

Comment: Approximatley which distance will you move? How much cats are in this neighbourhood in average?

Comment: We're moving to a new house in a 5-6 minutes walking distance, and there should be around 40 to 50 cats in the whole area, almost all friendly.

Comment: I would assume, that with this high density of cats, the territory around your new house is already taken. So relocate the cats would cause stress with the new neighbourcats. Depending of how "alpha" yours are, they would fight...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I really appreciate it. And do you think if they want to get back to their previous territory they'd be lost on their way back? (I'm talking about between 400 to 800 meters tops, depending on where we settle down, as we're trying to find a rental in the same gated community) The reason I am thinking about moving them with me is that I just want them to have both options, so if they don't want the new house they can go back to the previous one and just come to us for food without getting lost in the process.

Comment: I would assume they will not get lost in a way of lost direction. But depending of the other cats they could have difficulties to cross territories of other cats. But I am no cat expert so you may wait for another more skilled person to answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Allerleirauh.

Comment: If you want to be sure that the other person gets a message about your comment, you would write "@Allerleirauh" into it :) In the other case I would get no message that a comment is waiting for me ;) I am happy to help and wish you and the cats the best outcome for your plans!

Comment: @Allerleirauh Thank you again for all your help and support! :)